# how to set terraform variable type for value type map of strings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am currently passing the db option group settings as hard coded in the module code itself.

```
options = {

    TIMEZONE = {
      option_name                    = "Timezone"
      option_settings = {
        TIMEZONE = {
          name  = "TIME_ZONE"
          value = "Europe/Berlin"
        }
      }
    },
    NNE = {
      option_name                    = "NATIVE_NETWORK_ENCRYPTION"
      option_settings = {
        CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_SERVER = {
          name  = "SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_SERVER"
          value = "REQUIRED"
        },
        ENCRYPTION_SERVER = {
          name  = "SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER"
          value = "REQUIRED"
        },
        ENCRYPTION_CLIENT = {
          name  = "SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT"
          value = "REQUIRED"
        },
        ALLOW_WEAK_CRYPTO = {
          name  = "SQLNET.ALLOW_WEAK_CRYPTO"
          value = "FALSE"
        },
        ALLOW_WEAK_CRYPTO_CLIENTS = {
          name  = "SQLNET.ALLOW_WEAK_CRYPTO_CLIENTS"
          value = "FALSE"
        }
  }
}
```

To parametrize the same, I declared a variable, **options = var.db_options**
I want to understand, how can I create an appropriate variable type for the same.
I tried few ways but it always threw an error saying not a suitable type kind of.
So to make it work, I defined the variable type as map(any), which worked but I still want to know , what would be the appropriate variable type for such a value.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you tried with the errors you got. Maybe its just a quick fix, rather then expecting someone to do everything from scratch for you.

Comment: Hi sorry for my late response. I didn't had the history of what all I tried earlier.
The following form did worked,

variable "db_options" {
  type = map(
    object({
      option_name = string
      option_settings = map(
        object({
          name  = string
          value = string
        })
      )
    })
  )
}

But I was trying to make it a bit more generic than a very specific one.

But it's okay. I will work on it again sometime later maybe.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to take advantage of `any` variable type

```
variable "options" {
  type        = map(any)
  description = "Map of options"
  default     = {}
}
```

To go further, each key/value in the map can be defined in the variable type definition.

```
variable "options" {
  type = map(object({
    option_name     = string
    option_settings = map(object({
      name  = string
      value = string
    }))
  }))
  description = "Map of options"
  default     = {}
}
```

Comment: The OP already said `map(any)` is being used.

Comment: Woops. Thanks for the ping. I forgot to include the last code block.